# Seize the Day ... and the Key!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

In an effort to increase my cybersecurity, I recently went through the process of changing my passwords to be more complex and adding secondary passkeys for particularly important documents. The only problem is, I have now forgotten one of the passkeys and I need to get into the document.

Thankfully, I prepared for this possibility and have a notebook with cryptic hints to help me remember my new passwords and passkeys. Unfortunately even with the hints left, I still can't seem to figure this one out! Please help me figure out the passkey so I can access this document again.

> *This is the page in my notebook for the passkey:* 
> [image: Notebook page]

***What is the password?***

**Hint:**

> I remember adding the sticky note afterwards as a hint to help with the note... but I know the words on the sticky note aren't important...

Comment: This isn't your real password right . . . *pulls out notebook*

Comment: @Silvermidnight haha thankfully no

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer:
The words on the note are indeed not important because

> The caps spell QWERTY in 5 bit binary

Answer (score 2):

"Seize the day!" is also known as:

> [Carpe diem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpe_diem) from the Roman poet Horace.

What is the sticky note for?

> Maybe to remind you to "arbitrarily" (or better: appropriately) use small and capital letters.

Where are the numbers?

> "Carpe DIeM" contains the Roman numbers C=100, D=500, I=1 and M=1000

So, as a tentative guess, the password might be:

> 100arpe501e1000

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess this.

Is the password

> 20 5 23 18 4 19 14 20 13 20 18 5 15 21 25?

Why?

> Well, firstly, you have "Seize the day!  ... and the numbers". This has something to do with numbers. The second one "ThesE WoRDS do NoT MatTeR sEriOUslY."

> T E W RDS N T M T R E OU Y < are the seemingly random capital letters. I sometimes do this, but I put the capital and lowercase letters deliberately. FoR eXaMpLe . . .

> And if the words do not matter, and there are numbers, it would be simple to convert the letters to words. This way, seizing the numbers makes sense and the words don't matter, the numbers DO.

Comment: Not quite, but I like the thinking! Keep at it!